# Como hago para limpiar un validators con una función o como cambio un required de falsa a true con una función?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Hola necesito que cuando doy en el radio "no" mi validador cambie a false  y cuando doy en el radio "yes" mi validador cambie a true , estoy trabajando con angular .

```
        <label class="labelx">Upload item as issue in CIMT service?</label>
    <div>
      <input (click)="clickAddText()"  type="radio" name="button" id="opt1">
      <label for="opt1" class="label1" >
        <span>YES</span>
      </label>
      <input (click)="clickTextNone()"  type="radio" name="button" id="opt2" checked>
      <label for="opt2" class="label2">
        <span>no</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="show">
      <label>Description:</label>
      <textarea id="ta" type="text" name="description" formControlName="description" class="form-control"
      [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submittedItem && itemControls.description.invalid }" [readonly]="itemSaving" required = false> </textarea>
      <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submittedItem && itemControls.description.invalid">
        <p *ngIf="itemControls.description.errors.required">Description is required.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

fin de codigo html

Logica en typescript
Codigo angular typescript:

```
    import { Component, OnInit , Output, EventEmitter, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
    import { NgbModalConfig,   NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    import { CcmApiService } from '../../../services/ccm-api.service';
    import { HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
    import { JsonValidator } from '../../../validators/json.validator';
    import { fileNameValidator } from '../../../validators/file-name.validator';
    import { ValidateNameNotTaken } from '../../../validators/async-name.validator';
    import { ValidateFileNameNotTaken } from '../../../validators/async-file.validator';
    import { AlertNotification } from '../alerts/alert-notification';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    
    export class Item {
      public name: string;
      public type: string;
      public properties: string;
      public file;
      public version: string;
      public description: string;
    }
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-new-item',
      templateUrl: './new-item.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./new-item.component.sass']
    })
    export class NewItemComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    
      @Output() newItem: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
      postItem: Subscription;
      typeItems: Array<string> = environment.typeItems;
    
      modelItem = new Item();
    
      loading = false;
    
      itemForm: FormGroup;
      submittedItem = false;
      progressBarValue = 0;
      itemId: number;
      itemSaving = false;
      addItemToCIMT = false;
    
    
      constructor( configModal: NgbModalConfig,
                   private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
                   public ApiService: CcmApiService,
                   public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
        configModal.backdrop = 'static';
        configModal.keyboard = false;
      }
    
      addNewItem(formData) {
        this.postItem = this.ApiService.postNewItem(formData, this.addItemToCIMT).subscribe(
          events => {
            if (events.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
              this.progressBarValue = Math.round( (events.loaded / events.total) * 100 );
            }
            if (events.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
              if (HttpEventType.ResponseHeader === 2) {
                this.progressBarValue = 0;
                this.newItem.emit(events);
                this.itemForm.reset();
                this.activeModal.close();
                const alertSuccess = new AlertNotification().createNotification(
                  'success',
                  'Item Created Successfully',
                  `Name: ${events.body.name} <br> Type: ${events.body.type.toLowerCase()}`
                  );
              }
            }
    
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.activeModal.close();
            const alertError = new AlertNotification().createNotification(
                    'error',
                    'Failed to Create New Item ', `${error.error.error}
                    ${error.message}
                    `,
                    10000
                    );
          }
        );
      }
    
      get itemControls() {
        return this.itemForm.controls;
      }
    
      getFormData(properties: JSON) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('version', this.itemForm.get('version').value);
        formData.append('file', this.itemForm.get('file').value);
        formData.append('properties', JSON.stringify(properties));
        formData.append('name', this.itemForm.get('name').value);
        formData.append('type', this.itemForm.get('type').value);
        if (this.addItemToCIMT) {
          const subject =  'New ' + this.itemForm.get('type').value + 'loaded with name: ' + this.itemForm.get('name').value;
          formData.append('subject', subject);
          formData.append('description', this.itemForm.get('description').value);
        }
        return formData;
      }
    
      cancelPostItem() {
        if (this.postItem) {
          this.postItem.unsubscribe();
        }
      }
    
      public onSubmitItem() {
        this.submittedItem = true;
        if (this.itemForm.invalid) {
          return;
        }
        if (this.itemForm.valid) {
          let properties: JSON;
          const isPropertiesNull = (this.itemForm.value.properties === undefined || this.itemForm.value.properties === '');
    
          if (isPropertiesNull) {
            properties = JSON.parse('{}');
            this.itemSaving = true;
    
            const dataValues = this.getFormData(properties);
            this.addNewItem(dataValues);
            this.itemForm.get('type').disable();
            this.itemForm.get('file').disable();
    
          } else {
    
            properties = JSON.parse(this.itemForm.value.properties);
            this.itemSaving = true;
    
            const dataValues = this.getFormData(properties);
            this.addNewItem(dataValues);
            this.itemForm.get('type').disable();
            this.itemForm.get('file').disable();
          }
          const redmineIssue = {
            issue: {
              project_id: 'sabiamar-gs',
              subject: 'New ' + this.itemForm.get('type').value + 'loaded with name: ' + this.itemForm.get('name').value,
              tracker_id: 3,
              status_id: 1,
              priority_id: 4,
              description: this.itemForm.get('description').value
            }
          };
        }
    
      }
    
      onFileSelect($event) {
        if ($event.target.files.length > 0) {
          const file = $event.target.files[0];
          this.itemForm.get('file').setValue(file);
        }
      }
    
      ngOnInit() {
    
        this.modelItem.type = '';
        this.itemForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          version: [''],
          file: ['',
            { validators: [
               Validators.required
              ]
            }
          ],
          name: [null,
          {
           validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)],
           asyncValidators: [ValidateNameNotTaken.createValidator(this.ApiService)]
          }
          ],
          type: ['', Validators.required],
          properties: ['', JsonValidator],
          description: ['',Validators.required],
        });
    
        this.itemForm.patchValue({
          version: '1.0.0'
        });
    
        this.itemForm.get('type').valueChanges.subscribe(
          value => {
            const file = this.itemForm.get('file');
            if (value === environment.typeItems[3]) {
              file.setValidators(fileNameValidator());
              file.setAsyncValidators(ValidateFileNameNotTaken.createValidator(this.ApiService, 1000));
            } else if (value !== environment.typeItems[3]) {
              file.clearAsyncValidators();
              file.clearValidators();
              file.setValidators(Validators.required);
            }
        });
    
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.postItem) {
          this.postItem.unsubscribe();
        }
      }
    
      clickAddText() {
        document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'block';
        this.itemForm.get('description').setValidators(Validators.required);
        this.itemForm.updateValueAndValidity()
        this.addItemToCIMT = true;
      }
    
      clickTextNone() {
        document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'none';
        this.itemForm.get('description').clearValidators();
        this.itemForm.updateValueAndValidity()
        this.addItemToCIMT = false;
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bastaría con remover y agregar de nuevo las validaciones en cada operación que has definido:

```js
clickAddText() {
  this.itemControls.get('description').setValidators(Validators.required);
  this.itemControls.updateValueAndValidity()
}
clickTextNone() {
  this.itemControls.get('description').clearValidators();
  this.itemControls.updateValueAndValidity()
}
```

Suponiendo que `itemsControls` sea un `FormGroup`, de no ser así utilizalo directamente con el formGroup o si ya tienes registrado tu `formControl` utiliza la parte de `.setValidators(xxxx...`

Comment: lo habia intentado hacerlo asi inclusi con ese codigo que me pasaste cambiando el itemControls por el itemForm  pero no funciona ,

Comment: tu respuesta fue muy útil y debería funcionar pero no me funciona ahí agregue mas info en la publicación de la parte lógica en ts .

Comment: @JonatanAlexisSevero Y cual es problema? Aparte del lorem ipsum ...

Comment: el lorem no es el problema lo puse por que me faltaba agregar texto para que me deje subir el codigo ,

Comment: el problema es que no puedo sacar ni poner el required con las funciones que cree para el textarea description

Comment: Pero te da algún error? Puedes editar tu pregunta con esa información.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda , no me da ningún error , solo no me deja guardar cuando le doy a "no" que ejecuta la funcion clickTextNone()

Comment: Puedes hacer un ejemplo en https://stackblitz.com para ayudarte mejor. Replica solo una parte de tu lógica.

Comment: lo hice asi y funciono de todas formas voy a dar tu respuesta como valida por que es lo mismo creo

Comment: clickAddText() {
    document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'block';
    const description = this.itemForm.get('description');
    description.setValidators(Validators.required);
    description.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.addItemToCIMT = true;
  }

  clickTextNone() {
    document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'none';
    const description = this.itemForm.get('description');
    description.clearValidators();
    description.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.addItemToCIMT = false;
  }

Comment: muchas Gracias @Legna

Comment: Excelente. Lo importante es que se solucionó tu problema.